# js body random background image

Tags: javascript, random, background

This code should use any .jpg image from /images/bg/ folder, however it doesn't seems to be taking images below particular resolution...any suggestions?

```
<!--random background images from a folder-->

<script type="text/javascript">
        var totalCount = 5;
        function ChangeIt() {
            var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
            document.body.background = 'images/bg/' + num + '.jpg';
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you really mean resolution (pixels per inch), or do you mean size (pixels)? What threshold do you observe separating images that work and images that don't? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJCmC/1/)

`document.body.background` is deprecated, it should be `document.body.style.background` and the format you're giving it is wrong. Try

```
document.body.style.background = 'url(images/bg/' + num + '.jpg)';
```

The following also works and doesn't remove the other attributes of background, like backgroundSize for example, so you wouldn't need the line `document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";` as long as it was set in the first place.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/bg/' + num + '.jpg)';
```

So, your code would read

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.style.backgroundSize='cover';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat'; // i've assumed this
    var totalCount = 5;
    function ChangeIt() {
        var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/bg/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }
</script>
```

Though, ideally you'd set cover and no-repeat in a CSS file.

Comment: whilst your answer is correct, i'd like to extend it by pointing out that document.body.background is deprecated. use document.body.style.background = 'url(...)'; instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + 'images/bg/' + num + '.jpg' + ")";

(google about css background image).